# How to select meshes that are bundle into one object in blender?

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools

I want to select meshes that were bundled together into one object and remove them or move them apart. The mesh come bundles and I have no control over this part.

Can I select a mesh by clicking a mesh and hitting an action? Can I break apart the object into distinct meshes? I feel that it is quite eazy to do, but I didn't find a way to do it.

I tried to select one vertices and select the remainings that are connected, but I was not able to select them all.

[image]

Comment: what does it give if you select all and press P (Separate) > By Loose Parts? it should work if each arrow is made of one mesh

Comment: It works! Each arrow is its own mesh now. Thx!! :)

Comment: Don't forget to select all the new objects and right click > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Edit* mode select all and press <kbd>P</kbd> *(Separate) > By Loose Parts*. It will work if each arrow is made of one mesh. Also don't forget to select all the new objects and <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Set Origin > Origin to Geometry*